# LLM slow inference even on A100 GPU

Tags: nlp, gpu, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

I am planning to deploy a fine-tuned version of Open-Orca-Platypus-2. It takes around 13.5GB on the GPU. I tried using g4dn.12xlarge in AWS which has 4 GPUs, but the inference still takes around 40 seconds. I also tried it on A100 GPU provided by Colab, but still the same.

What am I doing wrong? Do I still need more computational power or is anything wrong with my code?

```
    from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
    import torch
    import os

    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1,2,3"
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    # Load model
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model_path,
        device_map="auto"
    )

    # Set the model to evaluation mode
    model.eval()

    # Load tokenizer
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("Open-Orca/OpenOrca-Platypus2-13B", trust_remote_code=True)

    def ask_bot(question):
        with torch.no_grad():
            # Tokenize input question
            input_ids = tokenizer.encode(question, return_tensors="pt").cuda()

            # Generate output
            output = model.module.generate(
                input_ids,
                max_length=200,
                num_return_sequences=1,
                do_sample=True,
                top_k=50
            )

        # Decode and extract the response
        generated_text = tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
        response = generated_text.split("->:")[-1]
        return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does take a long time to generate an output even on powerful GPUs. My use-case was a chatbot, so I figured it would be ideal to stream the output token by token as generated by the model. This reduced the perceived time although the actual output would remain the same.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, TextIteratorStreamer

    with torch.no_grad():
    # Tokenize input question
    input_ids = tokenizer.encode(question, return_tensors="pt", truncation=True).cuda()
    streamer = TextIteratorStreamer(
        tokenizer=tokenizer, timeout=60.0, skip_prompt=True, skip_special_tokens=True
    )
    def generate_and_signal_complete():
        output = model.generate(
            input_ids,
            max_length=1500,
            num_return_sequences=1,
            do_sample=True,
            top_k=50,
            streamer=streamer
        )
t1 = Thread(target=generate_and_signal_complete)
t1.start()
# Decode and extract the response
for new_text in streamer:
    yield new_text
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking the GPU utilization during inference to ensure efficient resource usage. Additionally, try explicitly moving the model to the GPU using `.to(device)`:

```
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path, device_map="auto").to(device)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
import torch
import os

# Set the device to GPU if available; otherwise, use CPU
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

model_path = "Open-Orca/OpenOrca-Platypus2-13B"
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path)
model = model.to(device)
model.eval()

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path, trust_remote_code=True)

def ask_bot(question):
    with torch.no_grad():
        # Tokenize input question and move to GPU if available
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(question, return_tensors="pt").to(device)

        # Generate output
        output = model.generate(
            input_ids,
            max_length=200,
            num_return_sequences=1,
            do_sample=True,
            top_k=50
        )

    generated_text = tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
    response = generated_text.split("->:")[-1]
    return response

question = "Your input question here"
response = ask_bot(question)
print(response)
```